# Wrong answer adopting right answer

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, accepted-answer

I recently answered a question which already was upvoted a little, but had a wrong answer (its comments acknowledged that).

The wrong answer then was edited to match in explanation the right answer, despite providing a slightly different method. It still has remnants of the wrong answer in it, making it somewhat confusing.

The OP then accepted the edited, now right answer.

While accepting the right answer (despite their bad style) seems okay to me, because its solution actually works, I wonder if it is the right way to "tune" an answer until it finally matches. Editing it this way would of course render the first comments of the discussion meaningless.

I guess the OP was tied to the wrong answer by the vivid discussion in its comments.

Despite all this, the result is now okay (I still prefer my answer, but that is no problem).

So was this an endorsable process, or should it be discouraged?

Comment: Some people use "accepted answer" to award the person that helped them the most.  If the answer is reasonable and answers the question, then it doesn't matter if it's not perfect - it's up to the OP to use their accept answer vote according to their conscience.

Comment: Besides which, if the answerer really did go out of their way in comments to help the OP, and keep their answer up to date, then they probably deserve the extra accepted reputation.

Comment: @AdamDavis yes, that what exactly I already thought. So I explecitely ask about if the process of editing one answer to a different one is to be to encouraged or not.

Comment: Hey, I explicitely do not ask about the reputation, but about the editing process.

Comment: For example, the poster of the answer could just post another, right answer.

Comment: @dronus If you've got an incorrect answer and you recognize it, then it should be edited, rather than making a new answer. If you feel it necessary, due to voting or comments, deleting it and submitting a new answer might make sense, but generally editing an existing answer to be better and more correct is preferred above making a new answer.

Answer (score 8):

> So was this an endorsable process, or should it be discouraged?

You say that as though it were a binary choice.

This practice shouldn't be encouraged. But it shouldn't be *discouraged* either. Remember: the goal is to provide good information. This is what (eventually) happened. So while this wasn't ideal, it was still overall a net win.

Editing not-good answers into good ones is overall productive.